# How to create specific class constructor

Tags: java, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a very simple Java JTable question.
I am creating this class to make things easier in the rest of my application. I receive an error when running it. I know what the errors mean, but have no idea what else to try.

You'll see in the code what I am trying to accomplish:

My Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class CPTable extends JScrollPane
{
    private JTable table;
    CPTable(Object [] headers, Object [][] data)
    {
        table = new JTable(data, headers);
        this = new JScrollPane(table);//The line I can't figure out.
    }
}
```

My errors: (an obvious one)

```
cannot assign a value to final variable this
    this = new JScrollPane(table);
```

and

```
incompatible types
found   : javax.swing.JScrollPane
required: CPTable
```

Comment: What do you expect that line to do? Why are you trying to assign a ScrollPane to `this`

Comment: Well, I simply want to instantiate the class. Usually it looks like this after you created the JTable: `JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);` , but since the class itself is the JScrollPane, how do you do that line?

Comment: See the answer by Chris Jester-Young, but why extend `JScrollPane`, I think that is bad (code) design.

Comment: The purpose of the class is to add an table to the application. The usual way to do it is to crate a table, add it on a scrollpane and then add the scrollpane to the content-pane. I want to skip a few steps. Make it quicker to code my project. (It has a lot of tables) This by simply having to create a table in one clean line only. I know what you mean I am actually working with a scrollpane - but by creating it, I add a 'table' to my screen, which is all I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private CPTable(JTable table) {
    super(table);
    this.table = table;
}

public CPTable(Object[] headers, Object[][] data) {
    this(new JTable(data, headers));
}
```

You cannot reassign `this`, but you can cause the correct superclass constructor to be called by using `super` (which must be the first statement in your constructor).

The `this` statement is called "constructor delegation"---it chains through to the other constructor so that you can pass the table to the superclass as well as assign it to your `table` field.

Comment: That answers the question, but I think he should change the design instead. A class that is named CPTable should probably not extend JScrollpane, since it then will be a scroll pane and not a table.

Comment: You are my super hero! :P (Thanks for teaching me something new!)

Comment: @Kaj it doesn't matter. If one wants an JTable (with headers) it has to be in a scrollpane; thus make life easier/quicker to make tables. (Its a small project I am doing...)

Comment: In what way will it make it easier? Note that the new class also takes  `JTable` as argument to the constructor, so the only difference is that you write `new CPTable(table)` instead of `new JScrollPane(table)`

Comment: @Kaj: That's not strictly true; the `JTable`-taking constructor (which is private) is simply a utility constructor used by the public constructor.

Comment: This is how I create a 'table' in my main class now: `CPTable newTable = new CPTable(column_names,column_data);` and `frame.getContentPane().add(newTable);`